# How to create the Window Setup for Odoo 8.0?

Tags: odoo, openerp-8

I have created so many  custom module in ODOO 8.0 adones and I want to create the ODOO Setup file for that for Window installation then Which kind of steps I want  to follow  or does it need to require for separate software that make my Window setup file.

Answer (score 2):

This document may helpful for you for  create window .exe file for OpenERP V6

please refere the below link :

https://doc.odoo.com/6.0/developer/8_24_build/

Answer (score 1):

You may try this V8 to see if it can solve your problem.

I've tried it on Windows 7, worked out of the box.

please try below link
http://sourceforge.net/projects/greenopenerp/files/

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i want step by step guide line to generate the .exe file.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11661079/creating-an-executable-file-from-python-script                                     https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/projects.html

Answer (score 0):

Hi there if somebody wants to simplify this, I made a small batch file to execute all of this procedure in a faster way..Just follow steps.Be sure to have odoo v8 installed on windows,not sure if it works with any other odoo version. Please download from this link:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/3p4071rlsa071is/CreateOdooModule.bat?dl=0

Also I did this in Windows 7 64 bits, maybe in other version it doesnt detect odoo path automatically.If not,just add it manually when program asks.

Hope it works for everybody !﻿

Comment: Sorry I see this was not original question but it popups when searching for odoo scaffold command in windows