# how to create odoo.exe from my odoo repertory?

Tags: odoo-8

Is there any possibility for me to add my modules into odoo.exe ,
that way they will be installed when someone install odoo.exe
or a way to create .exe from my odoo repertory  pleez help

Comment: This  Question is duplicated you can check below link                          http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27900677/how-to-create-the-window-setup-for-odoo-8-0

Comment: ok thx very much sire